# python setup.py sdist - SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

when I run the 'python setup.py sdist', i always meet with an error'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'.

the following is my source code:

***printlist.py***

```
def printlist(the_list):
for eachitem in the_list:
    print(eachitem)
```

***setup.py***

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='printlist',version='1.0',py_modules = ['printlist'])
```

both of these two files are placed in the same folder named 'myfolder'. and the version of Python is 3.2 on Windows XP platfrom.

Any ideas or options are appreciated!!!

Comment: Please post the *exact* error message, along with its traceback.

Comment: _If_ this is all of your code, and _if_ it has been transcribed correctly, then you are getting the syntax error because you need to indent the `for` block inside of your `printlist` function.

Comment: full traceback and full code please. Apart from that: your indentation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As Josh Caswell and pynator said, the syntax error likely comes from printlist.py, which should be intended like

```
def printlist(the_list):
    for eachitem in the_list:
        print(eachitem)
```

That said, I do not get any error when running `python setup.py sdist` on your programs with Python 3.2 on Mac OS X: distutils does not try to import your `printlist.py` module.  So, giving more details about the precise error you get, in your question, would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma after ['printlit']

It should look like this

```
setup(
    name='printlist',
    version='1.0',
    py_modules = ['printlist'],
)
```